# Can we enforce shell extension to call IShellIconOverlayIdentifier::GetOverlayInfo explicitly?

Tags: c++, winapi, com, windows-shell

We read a registry key in `GetOverlayInfo()` and `IsMemberOf()` methods to determine whether to show the overlay icons or not. From both of these methods we return `S_FALSE` if registry key is not set.

Problem is that when `GetOverlayInfo()` is called registry key is not set but it is set later in the session. I've noticed once `GetOverlayInfo()` returns `S_FALSE`, shell doesn't call `IsMemberOf()` further.

This registry key is set/reset from a different process(our application) while `GetOverlayInfo()` and `IsMemberOf()` runs within explorer (which is obvious)

I am looking for ideas to make my scenario work i.e. After registry key is toggled somehow `GetOverlayInfo()` should be  called at least once.  I've not found any way to do on web so far.

I tried to delete "Iconcache.db" file but that didn't enforce explorer to call `GetOverlayInfo()` again.

Can we clear explorer's cache programmatically ? That might enforce explorer to call `GetOverlayInfo()` again?

Edit 1 -
I read somewhere that there was article published in 98 issue of Window's Journal(WDJ) under title "rebuilding internet shell icons cache". Perhaps this article will help but I don't find it on web. Anybody has clue ?

Edit 2- Here is the sample code. Since I am returning `S_FALSE` from `GetOverlayInfo()` method which means we are telling explorer to ignore this overlay icon from now on for current session therefore explorer don't call `IsMemberOf()` further.  Now if sometime later registry value is toggled then I want explorer to call `GetOverlayInfo()` again. Is that possible ?

```
STDMETHOD(IsMemberOf)(LPCWSTR path, DWORD attr)
{

     ......
     ......
    // Check if icons are visible...
    if(!s_bOverlay)
    {
        return S_FALSE;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

STDMETHOD(GetOverlayInfo)(LPWSTR pwszIconFile, int iLength, int* piIndex, DWORD* pdwFlags)
{       
    // Check if icons are visible...
    if(!IsHandler(0))
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    if(g_moduleName[0])
    {
        wcsncpy(pwszIconFile, g_moduleName, iLength - 1);

        // Retrieve the icon index...
        *piIndex  = static_cast<T*>(this)->GetIconIndex();
        *pdwFlags = ISIOI_ICONFILE | ISIOI_ICONINDEX;

        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_FAIL;
}


bool IsHandler(const UINT uiState)
{
    s_bOverlay = true;  // static variable
    if(ERROR_SUCCESS == reg.Open(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\XYZ\\ABC", KEY_READ))
    {
        DWORD value = 1;

        reg.QueryDWORDValue(L"PQR", value);

        if(0 == value)
        {
            s_bOverlay = false;
        }
    }
return s_bOverlay; 
}
```

Comment: First of all, `S_FALSE` is not a valid return value for `GetOverlayInfo`. If you fail to provide info, then you're saying "I don't have an overlay icon after all, sorry for the confusion." If you have an icon that is simply not active yet, then return your icon and return `S_FALSE` from `IsMemberOf`. The problem has nothing to do with the icon cache. The problem is that your overlay handler said "Ignore me from now on" when you really wanted to say "Keep using me, because I might have something to say in the future."

Comment: @RaymondChen I see S_FALSE is not a valid return. Perhaps orignal developer had written this code intentionally with the same thought "ignore me from now on". It was serving the purpose till now but not anymore. I can fix the problem easily by reading the registry key from IsMemberOf() method every time it is called but I fear it might cause performance impact.That's the reason I am hesitating to amend current design which is serving the purpose from years.

Comment: `S_FALSE` is the same as an error. It causes the overlay to be considered invalid. And if you don't check the registry key. who will? Were you expecting Explorer to recheck your shell extension any time any registry key changes anywhere in the system?

Comment: @RaymondChen I've added the sample code in the post. Earlier idea was to read registry value only once. Any change in the state of registry key would be effective on next log on. Now I want to make registry key change effective without re-log on *but* also don't want to read from registry every time from IsMemberOf() method.

Comment: You get only one call to GetOverlayInfo. Make it count..

Comment: @RaymondChen Got it.  Can we force explorer to call GetOverlayInfo() programatically ? May be by clearing Icon's cache ? How ?

Comment: What I say three times is true. You get only one call to GetOverlayInfo. If you intend to return overlays at any time in the future, that call must succeed.

Comment: @RaymondChen  I changed to code to return S_OK from GetOverlayInfo() that's not a problem. Now question is how will come to know when GetOverlayInfo will be  called again ? Can we force explorer to call GetOverlayInfo explicitly ?

Comment: What I say four times is true. You get only one call to GetOverlayInfo.

Comment: Accepted ! I gave up. Thanks Raymond :-)

Comment: If you keep asking the same question you will get the same answer. Not sure what you were expecting to happen by repeating the question.

Comment: Ok, so what I concluded from this discussion is that - You get only one call of GetOverlayInfo() method in a session. If you return an invalid value from it then IsMemberOf() method will not even be called.  But if you return valid value from it then IsMemberOf() will be called. And we can't reset Icon's cache programatically. Is my understanding correct ?

Comment: I'm not going to repeat myself a fifth time.

Comment: Thanks. I got my answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

For those following this thread.Here is the summary of discussions I had with Raymond in comment section.

You get only one call of GetOverlayInfo() method in a session. If you return an invalid value from it then IsMemberOf() method will not even be called. But if you return valid value from GetOverlayInfo() then IsMemberOf() will be called. **And we can't reset Icon's cache programatically.**

Comment: The icon cache is unrelated. Even if you could reset the icon cache, the new icons won't use your overlay handler.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am curious to know from the beginning of this thread how to reset icon cache. I don't find any information on web.

Comment: See previous comment.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just move the call to `IsHandler` to `IsMemberOf` (and at least for now, drop the caching)?

Comment: I didn't want to read from registry every time IsMemberOf is called for performance reasons. That's why I created this thread.

Comment: That's not true! Kill explorer.exe + delete %localappdata%\IconCache.db